# Multiple pipe implementation using system call fork() execvp() wait() pipe() - it is simply not working

Tags: c, shell, fork, pipe, waitpid

I need to implement my shell that handles multiple pipe commands. For example I need to be able to handle this: `ls | grep -i cs340 | sort | uniq | cut -c 5`. I am assuming the problem is that I am not passing output of the previous command to the input of the next command.
When I execute my code, it gives me no output. I am using this pseudo code:

```
for cmd in cmds
    if there is a next cmd
        pipe(new_fds)
    fork
    if child
        if there is a previous cmd
            dup2(old_fds[0], 0)
            close(old_fds[0])
            close(old_fds[1])
        if there is a next cmd
            close(new_fds[0])
            dup2(new_fds[1], 1)
            close(new_fds[1])
        exec cmd || die
    else
        if there is a previous cmd
            close(old_fds[0])
            close(old_fds[1])
        if there is a next cmd
            old_fds = new_fds
if there are multiple cmds
    close(old_fds[0])
    close(old_fds[1])
```

Here is the source code of the function that handles multiple pipes.

```
void execute_multiple_commands(struct command ** commands_to_exec,
        int num_commands_p)
{
    pid_t status;
    int i, err;
    int new_fd[2], old_fd[2];
    pid_t pid, cpid;

    // creating child process
    if ( (cpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create child process, exiting...");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) // in the child process we run multiple pipe handling
    {
        for (i = 0; i < num_commands_p; i++) // for each cmd in cmds
        {
            if (i+1 < num_commands_p) // if there is next cmd
                pipe(new_fd);

            if ( (pid = fork()) == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not create child process, exiting...");
                exit(1);
            }

            if (pid == 0) // if child
            {
                if (i != 0) // if there is a previous command
                {
                    dup2(old_fd[0], 0); // setting up old_pipe to input into the child
                    close(old_fd[0]);
                    close(old_fd[1]);

                }
                if (i+1 < num_commands_p) // if there is a next cmd
                {
                    close(new_fd[0]); // setting up new_pipe to get output from child
                    dup2(new_fd[1], 1);
                    close(new_fd[1]);

                    err = execvp(commands_to_exec[i]->args[0], commands_to_exec[i]->args);
                    status = err;
                    exit(err);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
                if (status == -1)
                    exit(1);

                if (i != 0) // if there a previous command
                {
                    close(old_fd[0]);
                    close(old_fd[1]);
                }
                if (i+1 < num_commands_p) // if there a next cmd
                {
                    old_fd[0] = new_fd[0];
                    old_fd[1] = new_fd[1];
                }
                exit(0);
            } // end if
        } // end for

        if (i) // if there a multiple commands
        {
            close(old_fd[0]);
            close(old_fd[1]);
        }
    }
    else // in the parent process we are waiting for child to handle multiple pipes
        waitpid(cpid, &status, 0);
}
```

Function `execvp()` takes array of structures. Ive checked all my parsing part, and it works fine. It is the `execute_multiple_commands()` function that I am having trouble with.

Here is the code for struct:

```
// name: command
// desc: holds one command (meaning that it can be
//        more than one token in that command)
//        "ls -la" will be an example of one command
//       holds num of tokens in command array
struct command
{
    char ** args;
    int num_args;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a new strategy, R2:

```
function do(commands)
    if commands is of size 1
        exec commands[0] || die
    split commands into c1 (first command) c2 (the rest of them)
    open
    if fork 
        close input end of pipe
        dup output of pipe to stdin
        do (c2) || die
    close output end of pipe
    dup input of pipe to stdout
    exec c1 || die
```

Using a recursive function, especially if you're maintaining a list, will help you simplify your logic.  You don't really have to worry about stack depth here, as your whole address space will be overwritten anyway.

In other news, from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2):

> After a successful return from one of these system calls, the old and
>   new file descriptors may be used interchangeably. They refer to the
>   same open file description (see open(2)) and thus share file offset
>   and file status flags; for example, if the file offset is modified by
>   using lseek(2) on one of the descriptors, the offset is also changed
>   for the other.

Which meanse when you say you're closing both ends of the pipe?  You really are closing it - it AND the standard in/out that your program is intending on using.

--> MUCH LATER EDIT <--

As Jonathan Leffler pointed out, the above information is in correct.  I have confirmed it with the following program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    dup2(0, 7);
    write(7, "Hey, 1\n", 7);
    close(0);
    write(7, "Hey, 2\n", 7);
    close(7);
    write(7, "Hey, 3\n", 7);
}
```

Which results in the following output:

```
$ gcc dup2Test.c && ./a.out
Hey, 1
Hey, 2
```

Thanks, Jonathan!

Comment: Your interpretation of the man page for `dup2()` is incorrect. In general, if you have a pipe (two file descriptors) and you use `dup()` or `dup2()` to map one end to your standard input or standard output, then you should close _both_ file descriptors from `pipe()` to ensure that EOF is generated properly. The `close()` closes an open file descriptor; it only closes the open file description if there's no other file descriptor referencing it. But `dup2()` leaves you with two open file descriptors referencing the same open file description. (Yes, descriptors vs descriptions _is_ confusing!)