# Implementation of multipipes

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a simple shell and I would like to implement a pipes.

So, let's consider:

```
<command1> | <command2> | <command3> | ...
```

Now, my idea is:

Start command1 and waitpid for him. Then run command2 and waitpid for him. And so on.

1. Is it a good idea?
2. How to implement?:

   ```
   <command1> | <command2> | <command3> &
   ```

Comment: I think it is not a good idea. If you do so, you will have to save all of command1's output (potensially very big) to somewhere (memory or disk) and then pass it to command2.

Comment: This question is similar to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981199/multiple-pipe-implementation-using-system-call-fork-execvp-wait-pipe-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, my idea is:
>
> Start command1 and waitpid for him. Then run command2 and waitpid for him. And so on.
>
> Is it a good idea?

No. Start maybe reading [`pipe(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe). Processes have to run at the same time for communicating through a pipe. (and you **want** to use actual pipes for this, not some temporary storage).