# popen does not trap all the outputs of a command

Tags: c, linux, qt, popen

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    FILE* file1 = popen ("make", "r");

    char buff[5122];

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), file1)!=NULL)
    {
        qDebug() << "from here: " << buff;
    }


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral ("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

With `make` command the output is:

`QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.`
`from here:  make: Nothing to be done for`first'.`

With `ping` command the output is:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
            [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
            [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
            [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
```

---

As you can see, with `make` command the output was trapped and displayed by `qDebug`. **But, this isn't the case with `ping`**.

**Be it an error or whatever, I want every output to be trapped and displayed through qDebug through my program.**

What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code:

```
FILE* file1 = popen ("make", "r");
```

you can use whatever *shell* command is useful on the machine.  For instance, you can redirect the *standard error* to the same destination as the *standard output*, and capture *both* via the pipe:

```
FILE* file1 = popen ("make 2>&1", "r");
```

Further reading:

- [c popen won't catch stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900577/c-popen-wont-catch-stderr)
- [how to control popen stdin, stdout, stderr redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection)

While it is technically possible to open multiple pipes to a subprocess, it is much more complicated than the single-line call to `popen`:

- [Does this multiple pipes code in C makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948221/does-this-multiple-pipes-code-in-c-makes-sense)
- [How do I use two pipes in Unix C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059723/how-do-i-use-two-pipes-in-unix-c)
- [Multiple pipe implementation using system call fork() execvp() wait() pipe() - it is simply not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981199/multiple-pipe-implementation-using-system-call-fork-execvp-wait-pipe-i)